# GWT composite dynamic height resize

Tags: gwt, composite, autoresize

I Have a GWT Composite to which some other Composites are added dynamically.
I want to make may Parent composite Resize to fit the height of all its child widgets automatically.
i tried setting setHeight("100%") for Composite but this doesn’t work.
any Idea how to accomplish this functionality?

thanks.
EDIT:

```
final DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    dockLayoutPanel.setStyleName("EntryPanel");
    dockLayoutPanel.setSize("142px", "72px");
    initWidget(dockLayoutPanel);

    final VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    panel.setSize("140px", "72px");

    chckbxExport = new CheckBox("Export");
    putField(CommonPresenter.CONSTANTS.EXPORT, chckbxExport);

    dateBox = new DateBox();

    dateBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(final ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
            dateChanged = true;
        }
    });

    panel.add(dateBox);

    final ListBox visibility = new ListBox();

    final Label lblVisibility = new Label("Visibility:");
    LabeledWidget vis = new LabeledWidget(lblVisibility, visibility);

    for (int i = 0; i < CommonPresenter.CONSTANTS.VISIBILITIES.length; i++) {
        visibility.addItem(CommonPresenter.CONSTANTS.VISIBILITIES[i]);
    }

    putField(CommonPresenter.CONSTANTS.VISIBILITY, visibility);

    panel.add(vis);
    panel.add(chckbxExport);

    dockLayoutPanel.add(panel);
```

UPDATE:
Setting Composite width to fill all available Window horizontal space:

```
 final int scrollBarWidth = 25;
// editPanel.setHeight("180px");
setWidth(Window.getClientWidth() - scrollBarWidth + "px");
// editPanel.setStyleName("EditorPanel");

Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler()
{
  public void onResize(ResizeEvent event)
  {
    int width = event.getWidth();
    setWidth(width - scrollBarWidth + "px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it generally with HTML+CSS:

- Create the parent, and **do not** set its height (or set it to `auto`).
- Then add the children (just make sure, that you **don't use** `absolute`/`fixed` positioning for the children).
- Set the height of the children, if required.

The height of the parent will then be adjusted automatically. This is the same for GWT Composites - just make sure, which CSS (including style attributes) applies to your elements! If unsure, use Firebug.

If you need more specifics, then you'd have to post some code which shows how you construct the parent composite (UiBinder, ...?)

Comment: hello,I have a strange behaviour for the Composite I included under Edit. only the export checkbox is shown. i suspect it to be related to VerticalPanel but can't figure out. what's wrong in code above?

Comment: @othman: `DockLayoutPanel` s use `absolute` positioning... As mentioned in my answer, the children must not use this - it can never work, because absolutely positioned children don't influence the parent's size (that's what absolute positioning is)! Try using a `FlowPanel` instead. You probably also don't need the `VerticalPanel` (?)

Comment: Thanks chris-if DockLayoutPanel should not be used that means i should look for other GWT Panels to layout my widgets. what are the standard GWT Panels that don't use absolute positioning and offer flexibility for laying out my widgets? thanks much

Comment: @othman: The basic panel that I would recommend is `FlowPanel` - everything else depends completely on what you want to achieve. By the way, a lot of things can be done with FlowPanel, if you use CSS to position the children (this can be a good technique, and is even [suggested](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) by the GWT team).

Comment: Chris, I'm not sure what you mean by absolute positioning? In fact there is a AbsolutePanel which does this but DockLayoutPanel is positioningits children in areas (North,south, west,center) this isnot absolute positioning unless this word has another meaning for you.what's your comment?

Comment: @othman: I mean `position: absolute;` in CSS. Please use Firebug (or a similar tool) to inspect the generated HTML elements - you'll see, that DockLayoutPanel uses absolute positioning.

Comment: thanks chris -using VerticalPanel and HorizontalPanel instead of DocklayoutPanel solved the issue ! - for width i need my Composite to fill all Window horizontal spece . i did that by code updated at OP .is there another better way to setWidth and auto-resize width ?

Comment: @othman: It would be better to open a new question for the width problem (it's a separate problem). Did you try to simply set the width to `100%`?

Comment: Hi Chris, it seems setting width to 100% doesn't work. In fact the Composite i want to set its width is wrapped inside another DeckPanel which is also wrapped inside a VerticalPanel (we have a quit complex UI app). so maybe the UI Components three is too deep and i need to set also the width of higher UI Components?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "100%" you can get the actual height by Window#getClientHeight(). To handle scenarios where the user resizes the browser, you can use a ResizeHandler.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, the OP doesn't want to resize the composite based on the browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding the Resize()(Your class must extend to ResizeComposite).
In this re-size method set the size you want.

This works you dynamically because every time the window is re-sized this method is called and the values are set accordingly.